# PSR standard for short-echo tags spacing

Tags: php, coding-style, standards, psr-1

The PSR coding standards are very clear about most of their conventions, including the very first entry in PSR-1:

> PHP code MUST use the long `<?php ?>` tags or the short-echo `<?= ?>`
>   tags; it MUST NOT use the other tag variations.

but what is not clear and has been questioned recently in our team is about the spacing, particularly for the short-echo tags.  We would normally see a `<?php` opening tag on its own line at the top of a file or if it is an in-line statement then it will fail to parse if there is no space.  So the rule here seems self explanatory.

```
<?php
//tag followed by new line - fine
$obj = new Foo();
?>
<p>Hello <?php echo $obj->printBar(); ?> World</p>
//tag followed by space - fine
<p>Hello <?phpecho $obj->printBar(); ?> World</p>
//tag no space - Parse Error
```

My question is what about the short-echo tags `<?= ?>`, with and with out a space after the opening tag parses fine - but which is PSR standard compliant?

```
<p>Hello <?= $obj->printBar(); ?> World</p>
//tag followed by space - parses okay
<p>Hello <?=$obj->printBar();?> World</p>
//tag no space - parses okay
```

Comment: If nothing mentioned - choose one style for your team and use it.

Comment: There *is* a space in the example. What's ambiguous?

Answer (score 2):

Add a space for consistency across the short and long PHP open tags.